# How to stop a running queued Job in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I am using redis queue on laravel. Everything is working perfectly.

I also showing the jobs in queue in Front-End. Now I want to make a request from frontend to kill a job which is already running or in progress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it from the front end the only way ( *I know of* ) would be to keep checking an entry on the database table using Query Builder (or even Eloquent) from your job's `handle()` method and stopping from there.

For Example, you can have a table on your database, say `job_statuses` which will have a `job_id` and a `status` column. Then you can create a route to alter the status column to something like `aborted`. Now in your `Job` class' `handle()` method check if the status is aborted after some iterations and throw an exception **OR** call the Job's `fail($e)` method to gracefully stop the Job and do some additional logic. like so:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

if(DB::table('job_statuses')
    ->where('job_id',$this->getJobId())->first()->status === 'aborted'){
                //throw new Exception('Aborted by user.');
    }
```